# Was John Houseman cast in Rollerball in part because of a certain resemblance to Leonid Brezhnev?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, rollerball-1975

I was re-watching [*Rollerball*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073631/) (1975) last night, and something struck me that I hadn't noticed before.  The proximate villain in the film is played by John Houseman, who after decades working as a producer and director, was moving into acting, after winning a suprise Oscar for his role in [*The Paper Chase*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070509/) (1973).  Seeing the multiple scenes in the film with Houseman's character, Mr. Bartholomew, watching the rollerball matches, I was struck by something that might have seemed much more obvious in the movie's original 1970s milieu.  (My fourteen-year-old son, naturally, was completely oblivious.)  Here is Houseman, posed symbolically over the reflected flames of his hellish sport.

[image: Rollerball]

(Bonus points for noticing that the aide sitting next to him is Admiral Motti.)

The images of Houseman watching his team play reminded me of images of the Soviet dictator Leonid Brezhnev watching hockey.  Even in the West, Brezhnev was known for being a huge hockey fan.  (He personally helped set up the 1972 eight-game Summit Series between a Canadian national team with players from the National Hockey League and a Soviet national team drawn largely from the Red Army hockey team, which was the first series played between the Soviets and Western professional players.)  Another thing the Soviet premier was well known for was his prominent, upward-slanting eyebrows.  Houseman's eyebrows are not as pronounced, but they reminded me ineffably of Brezhnev's.

[image: John Houseman at Bartholomew]

[image: Leonid Brezhnev]

Is there any information from the makers of the film—particular Normal Jewison, who produced and directed—that the Brezhnev imagery was intentional and affected the casting of the John Houseman as Bartholomew?

Comment: Maybe? Maybe it was subconscious, maybe it was deliberate. To me there isn’t much of a resemblance. More likely old sophisticated slightly overweight white guy just fit the mental image of evil in the 70s and 80s (and today perhaps!)